# Force PhoneGap to save JPEG instead of PNG form camera

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I currently have a working PhoneGap app that takes a picture and saves the image on to the server.

I am aware of PNG loading slower than JPEG, and this is why I want to change how phoneGap works.

Right now, when a user takes a photo, it is automatically sent to the server as PNG. How do I tell PhoneGap to force camera app to save JPEG? (TESTED USING CYMERA)

I've tried adding Camera.EncodingType.JPEG to the options, but still saves it as PNG.
here are the options I have used:

```
{quality: 70, allowEdit: true, sourceType: 1, destinationType: 0, targetWidth: 500, targetHeight: 500, encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?
Why isn't "Camera.EncodingType.JPEG" not making it save as JPEG?

Comment: Android quirks camera.encodingType is not supported http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Thanks I did not notice that in documentation! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using BASE64 encoding to get your image from the camera, you can try something like this (I did not tested it, but should work)

I hope you have Eclipse installed on your computer and you are not building in the cloud.

So open your MainActivity in eclipse and add the following line before your `super.loadUrl` call:

```
appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "YourActivityName");
```

Now after your onCreate add the following peace of code:

```
 @JavascriptInterface
 public String PNGtoJPEG(String my_image){
      byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(my_image, Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
      ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bao); 
      return Base64.encodeToString(bao.toByteArray(),Base64.URL_SAFE);
  }
```

When you finish with all this in your HTML file in your **cameraSuccess** function should look similar to this this:

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
//Only call Png to Jpeg IF we are on an android device.
if (device.platform!=='Android') {
var my_new_jpeg=window.YourAcitivityName.PNGtoJPEG(image);
}
}
```

Idea is that you call a custom function on the Java side which converts your Base64 Image back to a bitmap, than that bitmap is compressed as Jpeg and passed back to javascript as Base64 element.

Did not test in full if the code is working, but it should, let me know if it helped or not, if not I will build a quick app and test is myself.

**SOME SMALL UPDATES**

In your main activity you need to import some classes:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
```

Hope i did not forget any of them. If you are building on API lower than 17 than you have to remove the `@JavascriptInterface` line

One more think I see that you are using DroidGap, as far as I know that is an old and outdated version. It will probably work anyway but I do suggest to updated to the latest PhoneGap version, so your activity definition will look like this: `public class MobilePOS extends CordovaActivity` instead of `public class MobilePOS extends DroidGap`

I hope all of this helps a bit.

Emil

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as i was thinking of giving up and going for PNG. Compressing the image again is not a bad idea, I will try it now. Also, I am so new to this PhoneGap thing (my first app) that I didn't even know adding javascript from the java side was possible. Thanks. I do have a question though that is irrelevant, why is it under WindowClean? and now directly under window???

Comment: I'm getting the followin errors:
![Valid XHTML](http://i61.tinypic.com/bh0ggm.png)
<img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/bh0ggm.png" width="300" height="300">
In my manifest:
![Valid XHTML](http://i59.tinypic.com/2i7223r.png)

Comment: Please ignore my previous comments, I was trying to create an image preview. Here are links to the images http://i61.tinypic.com/bh0ggm.jpg
http://i59.tinypic.com/2i7223r.png

Comment: Sorry my fault, I was lazy and copy pasting from one of my projects, I have edited the function. Apologies for the typo

Comment: Also to fix those red underlines you need to import some classes, i will updated the answer shortly

Comment: Thanks for the great help and effort, but we have decided to just go with PNG instead. I will leave your answer as the answer, since I do think compressing it again to jpeg really is the solution. I will still test it though some other time when we finally decided to use jpeg on one of our apps. The app will be working on LAN only anyways so PNG or JPEG wont be much of an issue :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I have made a very small updated (again) to the Javascript in case somebody reads this, and they want to implement it cross platform, the Javascript should know only to call the native conversion function if the actual device is and Android one.